# Pandas: If statement with multiple conditions on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to compare rows within a group and if a condition is met within the rows, I want to either keep the complete group, keep the most recent row, or keep the first row.

The dataframe will only have 2 items per group. If the first row of the group has the LastFour digits of '2290' OR if it start with the letter 'M' AND if in the second row the LastFour column is equal to either 0087 OR 0117 AND if NUM != 6708 then I want to keep both rows. This is the first conditional. The second condition is if the rows are the same for each column except for the Date column then keep the row with the most recent date. Else, if neither of these conditions are met, keep the first row only and remove the second row.

Original df:

```
    KEY     CLAIM       LastFour    NUM     Date1       Date2     Code  
166 0944    163         0087        30087   3/2/2012    3/5/2012    1   
167 0944    164         0087        30087   3/3/2012    3/5/2012    1   
225 1413    222         2290        123422  2/10/2012   2/11/2012   1   
226 1413    223         0032        123123  2/10/2012   2/11/2012   1   
315 1979    312         0025        70025   12/24/2011  1/6/2012    3   
316 1979    313         0025        70025   12/24/2011  1/6/2012    3   
320 1997    317         0007        140007  1/1/2012    1/4/2012    2   
321 1997    318         0007        140007  1/1/2012    1/4/2012    2
```

Anticipated result:

```
    KEY     CLAIM       LastFour    NUM     Date1       Date2     Code  Keep
166 0944    163         0087        30087   3/2/2012    3/5/2012    1   FALSE
167 0944    164         0087        30087   3/3/2012    3/5/2012    1   TRUE
225 1413    222         2290        123422  2/10/2012   2/11/2012   1   TRUE
226 1413    223         0032        123123  2/10/2012   2/11/2012   1   TRUE
315 1979    312         0025        70025   12/24/2011  1/6/2012    3   FALSE
316 1979    313         0025        70025   12/24/2011  1/6/2012    3   TRUE
320 1997    317         0007        140007  1/1/2012    1/4/2012    2   FALSE
321 1997    318         0007        140007  1/1/2012    1/4/2012    2   TRUE
```

My approach was to use an if statement but I'm having trouble.

```
if ((df['KEY'] == df['KEY'].shift(-1)) & (df['LastFour'].isin(['2290'])) \
            | (df['LastFour'].str.get(0).isin(['M']))) & \
((df['KEY'] == df['KEY'].shift(-1)) & (df['LastFour'].isin(['0087','0117'])) | (~df['NUM'].isin(['670899']))):
    pass
if (df['KEY'] == df['KEY'].shift(-1)) & (df['LastFour'] == df['LastFour'].shift(-1)) & (df['NUM'] == df['NUM'].shift(-1)):
    df.groupby('KEY').Date.transform('last')
else:
    df.groupby('Key').iloc[0]
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: do you mean that every two rows makes up a group within which you apply the criteria?

Comment: In this situation, yes.

Comment: In your first conditional, you say if all of that takes place, keep both. What happens if the first conditional is False?

Comment: If the first condition is false, then check the second conditional and if that is false then in the else section just keep the first row of the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a fan with this approach, but it gets the job done...

I ended up creating the three rules separately. I ran the first two rules against the dataframe, but the third rule had some dependencies on the first two rules so I had to run that at the end. Before I ran the third rule, I made a smaller dataframe from the previous one by identifying rows that have not yet been altered after rule 1 and 2 completed. This is very convoluted but gets the job done.

```
PartA = ((df['KEY'] == df['KEY'].shift(-1)) & ((df['LastFour'].isin(LII_range)) | (df['LastFour'].str.get(0).isin(Begin_with))) & ((df['LastFour'].shift(-1).isin(s_term)) | (df['NUM'].shift(-1).isin(['670899'])))) \
| (((df['LastFour'].shift(1).isin(LII_range)) | (df['LastFour'].shift(1).str.get(0).isin(Begin_with))) & (df['KEY'] == df['KEY'].shift(1)) & ((df['LastFour'].isin(s_term)) | (df['NUM'].isin(['670899']))))

PartB = ((df['KEY'] == df['KEY'].shift(-1)) & (df['Date1'] == df['Date1'].shift(-1)) & (df['Code'] == df['Code'].shift(-1)) & (df['CLM_CD'] == df['CLM_CD'].shift(-1)) & (df['Date2'] != df['Date2'].shift(-1)) & (df['CLAIM'] > df['CLAIM'].shift(-1))) |\
((df['KEY'] == df['KEY'].shift(1)) & (df['Date1'] == df['Date1'].shift(1)) & (df['Code'] == df['Code'].shift(1)) & (df['CLM_CD'] == df['CLM_CD'].shift(1)) & (df['Date2'] != df['Date2'].shift(1)) & (df['CLAIM_NO'] > df['CLAIM_NO'].shift(1)))

PartC = ((df['KEY'].isin(C_Ids)) & ((df['KEY'] == df['KEY'].shift(-1)) & (df['CLAIM'] > df['CLAIM'].shift(-1))))|\
((df['KEY'].isin(C_Ids)) & ((df['KEY'] == df['KEY'].shift(1)) & (df['CLAIM_NO'] > df['CLAIM_NO'].shift(1))))

df['Keep'] = PartA | PartB # run through the first two rules

#Find the all unique rows that where 'Keep'==False and where 'Keep'==True, then subtract lists and store rows in list into a dataframe. Apply PartC rule on this dataframe.
C_F_Ids = df[df['Keep']==False]['KEY'].unique()
C_T_Ids = df[df['Keep']==True]['KEY'].unique()
C_Ids = [item for item in C_F_Ids if item not in C_T_Ids] 

#Rerun all the rules to cleanup all rows
df['Keep'] = PartA | PartB | PartC
```

Final Output:

```
    KEY     CLAIM       LastFour    NUM     Date1       Date2     Code  Keep
166 0944    163         0087        30087   3/2/2012    3/5/2012    1   FALSE
167 0944    164         0087        30087   3/3/2012    3/5/2012    1   TRUE
225 1413    222         2290        123422  2/10/2012   2/11/2012   1   TRUE
226 1413    223         0032        123123  2/10/2012   2/11/2012   1   TRUE
315 1979    312         0025        70025   12/24/2011  1/6/2012    3   FALSE
316 1979    313         0025        70025   12/24/2011  1/6/2012    3   TRUE
320 1997    317         0007        140007  1/1/2012    1/4/2012    2   FALSE
321 1997    318         0007        140007  1/1/2012    1/4/2012    2   TRUE
```